# WCF Service request and parameters sent via URL

Tags: wcf

I'm creating a WCF service (.net 4.5 - Visual Studio 2012) and I need to be abble to call my service operations and pass the right parameters via URL.

What do I need to change to allow this?

When I use the following URL: ".../MyService.svc/GetData?value=2", I get HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Here is my web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="ofertaServiceBehavior" name="Oferta" >
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""                 contract="GeoOfertas.IOfertaService" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ofertaServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"         multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="ofertaServiceBehavior" name="GeoOfertas.OfertaService">
            <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="" contract="GeoOfertas.IOfertaService" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ofertaServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"         multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```